# Remove the keys which are numbers and single character as string from dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I need to remove entries from the dictionary which key has a number or a single character.
Suppose I have dictionary `d = {"18/12/2015": 92, "test": 45, "H": 89, "test1": 76 , "50" : 37}`
I want result dictionary as a `d = {"test":45 , "test1": 76}`

Comment: The date has slashes in it.  What do you consider a number? If you are ignoring symbols, what other symbols can be ignored, or is it "keys with no letters"?

Comment: Please edit the code of your attempt to solve this problem into your question.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I am having numbers also in this type  edited the question and also keys with no or single letter

Comment: Probably easier to make a new dict that has only the keys you want, rather than remove unwanted keys from the existing dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either delete key value pairs in your original dictionary or just create a new one with only the keys you want to keep.
So e.g.

```
import re

d = {"18/12/2015":92 , "test":45 , "H":89 , "test1":76, "50": 37}

# simple predicate function to check your keys
# you could of course tune the regex to your needs, just an example
def predicate(val):
    r = re.compile('[0-9]+|[0-9]+\/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+')
    return len(val) == 1 or r.match(val)

# create a new dictionary with "unmatched" keys:
new_d = {key: value for key, value in d.items() if not predicate(key)}

# delete "matched" keys:
for key, value in list(d.items()):
    if predicate(key):
        del d[key]

print(new_d) # {'test': 45, 'test1': 76}
print(d) # {'test': 45, 'test1': 76}
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses sets to determine if there are any letters in the string.  `&` returns a set of characters that are in both sets, and a non-empty set is considered a True condition:

```py
import string

# upper- and lowercase letters are good
good = set(string.ascii_letters)

d = {"18/12/2015": 92, "test": 45, "H": 89, "test1": 76 , "50" : 37}

# dictionary comprehension to keep keys with good characters, but not if only 1 
d = {k:v for k,v in d.items() if len(k) > 1 and set(k) & good}
print(d)
```

```
{'test': 45, 'test1': 76}
```

It's not clear what you want to do with keys that are empty string `''` or just a symbol `/`.

Note above also creates a new dictionary.  If you literally need to remove keys from the original dictionary, then below finds the "bad" keys and deletes them:

```
import string

# upper- and lowercase letters are good, except if there is only 1.
good = set(string.ascii_letters)

d = {"18/12/2015": 92, "test": 45, "H": 89, "test1": 76 , "50" : 37}

# set of keys that are bad...reverse logic of previous example.
bad = {k for k in d if len(k) == 1 or not (set(k) & good)}
for k in bad:
    del d[k]
print(d)
```

```
{'test': 45, 'test1': 76}
```